# Change a radio button only if Ajax Call returns Sucess

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, radio-button, dom-events

In a HTML form, I have a group of Radio buttons. On `onchange()` event, it pushes its value via an Ajax call.

The Ajax call then hits the server and does the processing based on the value send by the call. It either returns a string `"success"` or `"failure"`.

If the return string is `"success"` then the radio button should stay put. In case of `"failure"` it should revert back to its last position.

What have I done? Well, I need to do similar thing for checkbox, and it is easy in case checkbox, I just uncheck the specific checkbox. I don't know how to record the last position of a radio button...

Any help?

Comment: please post your code

Comment: There is no code as of now.I need heads up on this one.

Comment: "What have I done?" - good question, what have you done? Provide some code maybe?

Comment: Posting your code will help, because, there are multiple ways to do this.

Comment: I do not want to club togehter an ugly solution. There for I need to know what is a good way to do it. I am not expecting any code in the Answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Is the old radio button value stored in your database? I ask this because: if it is, then you don't have to use a flag variable or anything like that to store the old value at the front-end. Your ajax call can return the old value along with the "failed" response

Comment: @om_deshpande: Perfect! That's the way to go... but what if the ajax request doesn't make it to the server? There will be no response and hence the solution should be local. Thanks man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever your last ajax request returned your success data after checking a radio button save the value of the checked radio into a variable.

When your next request returns failure data just get the value from your variable and check the according radio button.

**UPDATED CODE WITH AJAX REQUEST**

```
$(function(){

    var lastInput = 'r1';

    $('input').change(function(){

        var rdio = $(this);

        $.ajax({
          url: 'script.php',
          type: 'POST',
          dataType: 'json',
          'success' : function(response){
            if(response.status == 'success'){
                lastInput = rdio.val();
            }
            else{
                $('input[name="radio_group"][value="'+ lastInput +'"]').prop('checked', true);                
            }
          },
        });
    });
});
```

**Dummy Code**

```
$(function(){

    var lastInput = 'r1';

    $('input').change(function(){

        var rdio = $(this);

        switch(rdio.val()){
            case 'r1':
                lastInput = rdio.val();
                alert("Success");
                break;

            case 'r2':
                $('input[name="radio_group"][value="'+ lastInput +'"]').prop('checked', true);
                alert("Failure");
                break;

            case 'r3':
                lastInput = rdio.val();
                alert("Success");
                break;              
        }
    });
});
```

I did it without an Ajax request for testing purposes and simulated it with a Switch/Case statement, where the second condition shows the behaviour on failure.

http://jsfiddle.net/rYxUs/

Comment: I've updated the code above and included a dummy Ajax request, but the concept should be clear :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a flag variable to hold previous selected radio button.

If the ajax returns failure then try to check the previous radio button using flag variable.

use the following code to check previous radio button

```
$("input[name='radioButtonName'][value='valurFrom FlagVariable']").attr("checked", "checked");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
var radioValue = $("input[type='radio']").attr('checked');
```

and then on success:

```
$("input[type='radio']").attr('checked', 'checked');
```

on failure:

```
$("input[type='radio']").removeAttr('checked');
```

Answer (score 0):

worked fine for me.

$("input:radio[name='profile']").click(function(){

alert($(this).val());

});